# In what form is the energy stored in this situation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction, work

Consider a hypothetical situation, A person is pushing a block of some arbitrary mass in vacuum (no external forces are involved) and due to this, if I am not mistaken, the person is doing work and that work should be stored as energy in the block, but in what form is that energy stored in the block or something else is happening here?

Comment: As kinetic energy?  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually the energy is "stored" as kinetic energy in the block *and* the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push the block the block 'pushes' you with the same force and you both gain equal and opposite direction momentums. Both block, and you have now some momentum and hence kinetic energy. The work done on both you and the block is:

$$ W=\int F \,dx$$

where $F$ is a force applied. It must be equal to the total kinetic energy of you and the block (if no energy is lost due to the friction)

$$W=\frac{1}{2} m_{you}v^2_{you}+\frac{1}{2}m_{block}v_{block}^2$$

Obviously in a real situation some energy is converted into heat and kinetic energy is less than the work done.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! I switched your pictures to LaTeX. It's hugely preferred to have LaTeX written between $$ instead of putting pictures.

Answer (score 0):

In the pure hypothetical situation you pose, you, the block, and no forces from gravity, friction or wind resistance - the moment you 'push' the block you will impart a 'packet' of energy for only as long as you can extend your arms and maintain contact with the block. For at that moment the block will move away from you, and you will move away in the opposite direction, but at different velocities proportional to the relative masses (your body and the block). Once you lose contact with the block, there are no longer any forces, no further energy input. The block carries away that packet of energy which is now considered to be **kinetic energy** at a magnitude of $$\frac{1}{2}m_{block}v^2$$